Floating point precision loss in python numpy calculations
I have a very strange situation: I calculate angle between two vectors in spherical coordinate system. First I calculate scalar product of two vectors. Calculation using numpy array gives result with relative precision 10^(-16), as it should be for 64-bit floating numbers. But then I call acos and the angle from numpy's scalar product gives relative precision 10^(-11), i.e. 5 orders or magnitude worse compared to direct calculation (which is the correct result). Any ideas why?
#!/usr/bin/python
import numpy as np
import math

def testPrecision(theta1, phi1, theta2, phi2):

    # We define two vectors as numpy arrays
    t1 = np.array([math.sin(theta1) * math.cos(phi1), math.sin(theta1) * math.sin(phi1), math.cos(theta1)])
    t2 = np.array([math.sin(theta2) * math.cos(phi2), math.sin(theta2) * math.sin(phi2), math.cos(theta2)])

    # scalar product of vectors using numpy
    scalarProd1 = np.einsum('i,i', t1, t2)

    # scalar product of vectors without numpy
    scalarProd2 = math.sin(theta1) * math.cos(phi1) * math.sin(theta2) * math.cos(phi2) + math.sin(theta1) * math.sin(phi1) * math.sin(theta2) * math.sin(phi2) + math.cos(theta1) * math.cos(theta2)

    print("Scalar product:\nnumpy = {:.15e} vs direct = {:.15e}".format(scalarProd1, scalarProd2))

    alpha1 = math.acos(scalarProd1)
    alpha2 = math.acos(scalarProd2)

    print("Angle:\nnumpy = {:.15e} vs direct = {:.15e}".format(alpha1, alpha2))

testPrecision(theta1 = 1.745329251994330e-02, theta2 = 2.154759397163566e-02, phi1 = 1.745329251994329e-01, phi2 = 2.078144368653071e-01)

The result is
Scalar product:
numpy = 9.999914101231913e-01 vs direct = 9.999914101231911e-01
Angle:
numpy = 4.144849600753233e-03 vs direct = 4.144849600780019e-03


I think this is just a math problem. math.acos(1 - 2e-16) - math.acos(1 - 1e-16) is 6e-9.

Not sure if this helps, but this seems to be a problem of using np.einsum(). If you use scalarProd1 = np.dot(t1, t2) instead, then the numpy result will exactly match the direct result. Likewise, if you use scalarProd1 = np.einsum('i,i', t1, t2, optimize=True).

@ken you are right... thank you! can you post your answer, so that I can mark it as the solution?

@simon however for such input data both results are correct only to 10^(-6), that is why this is not very important.

@JohnSmith To my defense, I just looked at the printed numbers without trying to understand the underlying math :D
